# T-SQL / EF Where Col is true and false to filter result

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql, lambda

I have a stinking cold and can't for the life of me get my brain into gear to figure this out!

```
jobStops.Where(jobStop => jobStop.TrailerId == trailer.TrailerId && 
              (jobStop.IsDelivery == true && 
               jobStop.JobStopDateTime.Value.Date.CompareTo(date.AddDays(x).Date) >= 0) && 
              (jobStop.IsDelivery == false && 
               jobStop.JobStopDateTime.Value.Date.CompareTo(date.AddDays(x).Date) <= 0))
```

Obviously I know that we can't have where a column is true and false as that's impossible but what I'm after is the where statement to be read twice to filter itself down.

So the above query is basically saying, grab from the database the trailer row where it's delivered in the future and it's been collected in the past, so I know what's on the trailer at that time.

```
(jobStop.IsDelivery == true && 
 jobStop.JobStopDateTime.Value.Date.CompareTo(date.AddDays(x).Date) >= 0)
```

This deals with the items that are set for delivery in the future

```
(jobStop.IsDelivery == false && 
 jobStop.JobStopDateTime.Value.Date.CompareTo(date.AddDays(x).Date) <= 0)
```

This ultimately is meant to filter down the results of the above where clause so that it only shows items that have been collected.

I'm aware this is something probably really easy but the project was due for completion yesterday and I just can't get my head round it with this stinking cold.

Comment: where you use of (jobStop.TrailerId == trailer.TrailerId),this get only a row...for this reason jobStop.IsDelivery is true or false ...so you must use (||) Instead (&&) in second filter

Comment: You can use `>` and `<` instead of `CompareTo`. I assume this is EF-core?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Job ID

```
jobStops.Where(jobStop => ((jobStop.TrailerId == trailer.TrailerId && jobStop.JobId ==trailer.JobId)&& (
              (jobStop.IsDelivery == true && jobStop.JobStopDateTime.Value.Date.CompareTo(date.AddDays(x).Date) >= 0) ||
              (jobStop.IsDelivery == false && jobStop.JobStopDateTime.Value.Date.CompareTo(date.AddDays(x).Date) <= 0))))
```

Comment: The combine wouldn't work though as it would show all the items with delivery in the future AND all items collected. This is a case of needing to filter the list down so it's only showing items on the trailer at that time. Items already collected and out for delivery. I wondered if it would be a case of using .except() or similar.

Comment: Don't you have any other identity like job id or item id in your table?

Comment: Yeah we have job id.

Comment: yeah using job id you can do it I have updated my answer.